My springboot program cannot connect to the redis cluster. Why should I ask how to solve it?
I deployed three redis nodes on three servers, which are a distributed cluster, and then I had a springboot program, and the log output was abnormal when the program started
The exceptions in log printing are:
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationTokenFilter' defined in class path resource [com/hccx/archives/framework/security/config/ArchivesSecurityAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'authenticationTokenFilter' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'OAuth2TokenApiImpl': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'OAuth2TokenServiceImpl': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'OAuth2AccessTokenRedisDAO': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'stringRedisTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/redisson/spring/starter/RedissonAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'stringRedisTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'redissonConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/redisson/spring/starter/RedissonAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'redissonConnectionFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'redisson' defined in class path resource [org/redisson/spring/starter/RedissonAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.redisson.api.RedissonClient]: Factory method 'redisson' threw exception; nested exception is org.redisson.client.RedisConnectionException: Can't connect to servers!
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:165)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:175)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:155)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:97)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.callServletContainerInitializers(StandardContext.java:5766)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.callServletContainerInitializers(WebModule.java:609)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5662)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:526)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:885)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:868)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:644)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2079)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1694)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:83)
        at com.apusic.aas.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:98)
        at com.apusic.aas.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:267)
        at com.apusic.aas.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:358)
        at com.apusic.enterprise.v10.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:479)
        at com.apusic.enterprise.v10.server.ApplicationLifecycle.enable(ApplicationLifecycle.java:2163)
        at com.apusic.enterprise.v10.server.ApplicationLifecycle.enable(ApplicationLifecycle.java:90)
        at com.apusic.enterprise.v10.server.ApplicationConfigListener.enableApplication(ApplicationConfigListener.java:251)
        at com.apusic.enterprise.v10.server.ApplicationConfigListener.handleAppEnableChange(ApplicationConfigListener.java:183)
        at com.apusic.enterprise.v10.server.ApplicationConfigListener.transactionCommited(ApplicationConfigListener.java:144)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.config.Transactions$TransactionListenerJob.process(Transactions.java:343)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.config.Transactions$TransactionListenerJob.process(Transactions.java:334)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.config.Transactions$ListenerNotifier$1.call(Transactions.java:190)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.config.Transactions$Notifier$1$1.run(Transactions.java:144)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationTokenFilter' defined in class path resource [com/hccx/archives/framework/security/config/ArchivesSecurityAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'authenticationTokenFilter' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'OAuth2TokenApiImpl': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'OAuth2TokenServiceImpl': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'OAuth2AccessTokenRedisDAO': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'stringRedisTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/redisson/spring/starter/RedissonAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'stringRedisTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'redissonConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/redisson/spring/starter/RedissonAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'redissonConnectionFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'redisson' defined in class path resource [org/redisson/spring/starter/RedissonAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.redisson.api.RedissonClient]: Factory method 'redisson' threw exception; nested exception is org.redisson.client.RedisConnectionException: Can't connect to servers!
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:212)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:175)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:170)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAdaptableBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:155)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:262)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:236)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:193)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162)
        ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'OAuth2TokenApiImpl': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'OAuth2TokenServiceImpl': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'OAuth2AccessTokenRedisDAO': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'stringRedisTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/redisson/spring/starter/RedissonAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'stringRedisTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'redissonConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/redisson/spring/starter/RedissonAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'redissonConnectionFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'redisson' defined in class path resource [org/redisson/spring/starter/RedissonAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.redisson.api.RedissonClient]: Factory method 'redisson' threw exception; nested exception is org.redisson.client.RedisConnectionException: Can't connect to servers!
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:332)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
        ... 56 common frames omitted

springboot application.yml:
  redis:
    cluster:
      nodes:
        - 192.168.0.120:6379
        - 192.168.0.121:6379
        - 192.168.0.122:6379
      max-redirects: 3
    database: 1
    password: admin123 

redis.conf configuration file:
bind 0.0.0.0
pidfile  /var/run/redis_6379.pid
dir  /data/app/redis-data/data/
port 6379
masterauth admin123
requirepass admin123
timeout 300
daemonize yes
logfile "/data/app/redis-log/redis.log"
cluster-enabled yes
cluster-config-file nodes-1.conf
cluster-node-timeout 5000
appendonly yes
cluster-announce-ip 192.168.0.121
protected-mode no
databases 16

plz tell me why and how to solve it?

Post full exception. It looks like you omitted "cause by" part.

ok i already update my question detail

You need to find who throws RedisConnectionException. You can set breakpoint on exception in most IDE.

From the error log I can see you are using Redisson library. In this case you should provide different properties.
Yours:
  redis:
    cluster:
      nodes:
        - 192.168.0.120:6379
        - 192.168.0.121:6379
        - 192.168.0.122:6379
      max-redirects: 3
    database: 1
    password: admin123

Redisson (example):
spring:
  redis:
   redisson: 
      config: |
        clusterServersConfig:
          idleConnectionTimeout: 10000
          connectTimeout: 10000
          timeout: 3000
          retryAttempts: 3
          retryInterval: 1500
          failedSlaveReconnectionInterval: 3000
          failedSlaveCheckInterval: 60000
          password: null
          subscriptionsPerConnection: 5
          clientName: null
          loadBalancer: !<org.redisson.connection.balancer.RoundRobinLoadBalancer> {}
          subscriptionConnectionMinimumIdleSize: 1
          subscriptionConnectionPoolSize: 50
          slaveConnectionMinimumIdleSize: 24
          slaveConnectionPoolSize: 64
          masterConnectionMinimumIdleSize: 24
          masterConnectionPoolSize: 64
          readMode: "SLAVE"
          subscriptionMode: "SLAVE"
          nodeAddresses:
          - "redis://127.0.0.1:7004"
          - "redis://127.0.0.1:7001"
          - "redis://127.0.0.1:7000"
          scanInterval: 1000
          pingConnectionInterval: 0
          keepAlive: false
          tcpNoDelay: false
        threads: 16
        nettyThreads: 32
        codec: !<org.redisson.codec.Kryo5Codec> {}
        transportMode: "NIO"


Thank you, I wonder if I need to write another class to read this configuration if I modify this configuration
